# How to get list of xslt files from geoserver using rest api

Tags: python, geoserver, api, rest

I am trying to get list of all XML and XSLT files from GeoServer using REST API.

I am using path: my_geoserver/geoserver/rest/services/wfs/transforms

and code:

```
request_url = server + "/geoserver/rest/services/wfs/transforms.xml"
headers = {'Content-Type': 'text/xml'}
auth = ('user', 'pass')

r = requests.get(
request_url,
headers=headers,
auth=auth)


root = ET.fromstring(r.content)

xml_list = []
xml_path_list = []
for xml in root.findall('transform'):
    xml_name= xml.find('name').text
    xml_path= "my_geoserver/geoserver/rest/services/wfs/transforms/" + xml_name + ".xml"
    xml_list.append(xml_name)
    xml_path_list.append(xml_path)
```

With that code I get list of XML files

How can I get list of XSLT files?

Comment: My GeoServer refuses to admit that this is a valid endpoint but looking at the docs suggests that you need to set the response type to `application/xslt+xml` to see the actual XSLT

Comment: @IanTurton Thank you, that  is a solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My GeoServer refuses to admit that this is a valid endpoint but looking at the docs suggests that you need to set the response type to `application/xslt+xml` to see the actual XSLT